# Set height of row of table in Qt

Tags: visual-studio, qt, qtableview, qtablewidget

I want to create a table, my code in QtCreator:

```
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
ui->tableWidget->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnCount(5);
ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList() << tr("First") << tr("Second") << tr("Third") << tr("Fourth") << tr("Fifth"));

ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(0, 80);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(1, 140);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(2, 80);
ui->tableWidget->setColumnWidth(3, 140);
ui->tableWidget->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::section { background-color: rgb(217,217,217)}");
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true);

for (int c = 0; c < ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->count(); c++) {
    ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeaderItem(c)->setSizeHint(QSize(0, 50));
}

for (int j = 0; j < ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); j++) {
    QTableWidgetItem *item = new QTableWidgetItem;
    if ((j == 0) || (j == 3) || (j == 4)) {
        item->setFlags(item->flags() & ~Qt::ItemIsEditable);
    }
    if (j!=0) {
        item->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    }
    ui->tableWidget->setItem(0, j, item);
}
```

There is only one row in the table, I do it with Designer, so there is no line for the number of row in my code above.
Result:

[image: Qt]

With the same code above, I do in Visual Studio and receive this table:

[image: visual studio]

The height of row with VS is the height of the table, which is too large. How can I receive the small row as in QtCreator ?

Comment: Look at this : [qtablewidget-adjust-column-and-row-size](https://forum.qt.io/topic/9536/qtablewidget-adjust-column-and-row-size/2)

Comment: @Sirius: thank for your hint. I tried with that already but the table is still the same, no change.